# Android ScrollView is extremely slow rendering imageviews

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm displaying multiple imageviews in my layout which are added programmatically everything seems to be fine except the scrollview itself... it scrolls really slow and lags alot while scrolling. what can cause this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/jobs_container"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:** 've followed [THIS](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) and created my listview successfully, but yet again the listview itself lags while scrolling. I'm getting the imageview source from a webservice so basically my row item is like:

```
public class RowItem {
    private String imageSrc;
    private String title;

    public RowItem(String src, String title)
    {
        this.imageSrc = src;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getImageSrc()
            {
        return this.imageSrc;
    }
    public void setImageSrc(String src)
    {
        this.imageSrc = src;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return this.title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I basically get the list of json objects, convert'em to RowItem, then use the following code to generate the rows for listview:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    String url = rowItem.getImageSrc();
    url = url.replace("~", DOMAIN);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

and it still lags really bad.. any idea?

**UPDATE:** I think imageviews are causing the slow scrolling because before the images are downloaded and loaded everything's smooth but after the images are loaded it starts to slow down and on every scroll the hidden rows which will be shown reload the image again. could it be the reason?

Comment: If the "scrolling lags" it simply means that you are locking up the main UI thread in some place in your code, it's not related to the ScrollView itself. Locking up the main thread means doing too much CPU-intensive work on it.
This may be due to the fact that your images list is very long and not virtualized with ListView so it takes some time to render, or it can be something completely unrelated that your code performs on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using scrollView , you have to use ListView which has the scroll functionality and expands automatically as the items added

First step you have to define a layout as follows

```
 <LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            >

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

1. Implement Custom ListView adapter with getView() method

   View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
          View v = convertView;

   ```
      if(v == null)

         v = View.inflate(context , R.layout.your_item_layout_containing_image);

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewByID(R.id.your_image_view_id);

       Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(imageView);
       return v;
   ```

   }

Picasso is a library yoou can download and use directly to download images it has very good features

Comment: Thanks Muhannad, I'm already using Picasso and it works like a charm, I'll try this and will post back

Comment: I faced the same problem you posted in your answer in my early android days , but listView is the best View you will use in android applications , if you need any extra information on how to use ListView let me know

Comment: I've edited my question, would you please check it and see if you can find the problem ? thanks in advance

Comment: would you try cretaing another reference to the view like the following ; View v= convertView ; and in the end of the method return v; instead of returning convertView?